# Measuring the text width

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, uilabel

I am trying to draw some text with CoreGraphics. Unfortunately there is no method which returns the width of the text. I tried getting the width using this method:

```
private float GetTextWidth(CGContext context, string text)
    {
        float   startWidth, 
                endWidth,
                textWidth;
        startWidth = context.TextPosition.X;
        context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
        context.ShowText(text);
        endWidth = context.TextPosition.X;
        textWidth = endWidth - startWidth;
        return textWidth;
    }
```

but if I want a multiline text I also need to take the font into consideration. 
So I thought about using a UILable and get the values from it doing the following:

```
RectangleF lableRect = new RectangleF((float)rect.X, (float)rect.Y, (float)rect.Width, (float)rect.Height);
            UILabel lable = new UILabel(lableRect){
                Font = UIFont.FromName(font.Family.ToString(), (float)font.Size),
                Text = text,
            };
SizeF uiSize = lable.StringSize(lable.Text, lable.Font);
```

Although the height seems to be ok, the width is not correct. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `NSString`. It has various overloads like:

```
SizeF size = new NSString (s).StringSize (font, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation);
```

If you want a `UILabel` to fit the contained string you can also just call `UILabel.SizeToFit()`. Or if you want to know the size of a string in a UILabel, use `UILabel.StringSize()`

Comment: after doing some testing GetTextWidth returns the same width as label.StringSize and nsstring.stingSize, so I suppose everything is working, thanks.

Comment: Just a small question, is there a way to find the length of the truncated string?

Comment: That I don't know from the top of my head. Sorry.